# How can I get the compiler aliases of ValueTuple field names for reflection

Tags: c#, valuetuple

`ValueTuples` allow for compiler aliases for their public fields (`Item1`, `Item2`, etc...). For example:

```
    var tuple = (Name:"apple",Date:DateTime.Now);
    var nameFieldValue = tuple.Name;//"apple"
    //here tuple.Name is a compiler alias for tuple.Item1
```

Is there any way I can do the same thing via reflection?

```
    var tuple = (Name:"apple",Date:DateTime.Now);
    var nameFieldValue = tuple.GetType().GetField(nameof(tuple.Name)).GetValue(tuple);//null reference exception (the field is null)
```

I know I can do this:

```
    var tuple = (Name:"apple",Date:DateTime.Now);
    var nameFieldValue = tuple.GetType().GetField("Item1").GetValue(tuple);//"apple"
```

But I need to get the public fields based on their compiler aliases (`tuple.Name`), not the actual field names (`tuple.Item1`).

Comment: For a local variable, that's only present in the source code, I believe. For fields/parameters it's stored in attributes... but it's not part of the *type* itself. (You could have two different tuples with different names, but the type is identical.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Lets say I pass the tuple as a parameter to a function. How can I get the attributes of its fields to find the aliases?

Comment: Do you mean the names from the *calling* code, or the names in the *parameter*? (Because they may be different... and you wouldn't be able to get the ones used by the calling code.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Bummer. I want the names used by the calling code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tuple value names are a C# language construct akin to local variables and have no existence after the code is compiled.

The compiler will translate:

```cs
var tuple = (Name:"apple",Date:DateTime.Now);
var nameFieldValue = tuple.Name;
```

to:

```cs
ValueTuple<string, DateTime> valueTuple = new ValueTuple<string, DateTime>("apple", DateTime.Now);
string item = valueTuple.Item1;
```

and if you assign that tuple to another tuple with the same structure:

```cs
var tuple = (Name:"apple",Date:DateTime.Now);
(string foo, DateTime bar) otherTuple = tuple;
```

the complier will just generate this code:

```cs
ValueTuple<string, DateTime> valueTuple = new ValueTuple<string, DateTime>("apple", DateTime.Now);
ValueTuple<string, DateTime> valueTuple2 = valueTuple;
```

Try or yourself on https://sharplab.io/